# System.CommandLine mutally exclusive options

Tags: c#, system.commandline

I am using [`System.CommandLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/) and I wanted to create a mutually exclusive option. The user either has to use `--ipAddresses` and pass in list of one or more IP addresses OR use `--ipAddressesCsv` and pass in a file path containing the CSV file. I am wondering if its something possible to do with `System.CommandLine`.

This is my setup:

```cs
var ipAddressesOption = new Option<IEnumerable<IPAddress>>("--ipAddresses")
{
    Description = "The IP addresses",
    IsRequired = true,
    Arity = ArgumentArity.OneOrMore,
    AllowMultipleArgumentsPerToken = true,
};

var ipAddressesCsvOption = new Option<FileInfo?>("--ipAddressesCsv")
{
    Description = "CSV containing the IP addresses",
    IsRequired = true,
    Arity = ArgumentArity.ZeroOrOne,
    AllowMultipleArgumentsPerToken = false,
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Their suggestion in this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/issues/381) is to use a validator, something like this:

```
command.AddValidator(result =>
{
    if (result.Children.Count(s => s.Symbol == ipAddressesOption ||
                                   s.Symbol == ipAddressesCsvOption) != 1)
        result.ErrorMessage =
                  "You must use either --ipAddresses or --ipAddressesCsv";
});
```